# A GKScore must contain an initialized value?

Tags: ios, gamekit, sigabrt

I am getting a SIGABRT crash sometimes with the crash saying: A GKScore must contain an initialized value.

So it tracked it down to this line:

```
[localScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError* error) {}];
```

And localStore is created like this:

```
GKScore* localScore = [scores objectForKey:category];
```

-- category comes from...

```
for (NSString* category in categories)
```

-- categories comes from...

```
[GKLeaderboard loadCategoriesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *categories, NSArray *titles, NSError *error)
```

---

```
-(void) initScores
{
    NSString* libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* file = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentPlayerID];
    file = [file stringByAppendingString:kScoresFile];
    id object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:file];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* loadedScores = (NSMutableDictionary*)object;
        scores = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:loadedScores];
    }
    else
    {
        scores = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    //NSLog(@"scores initialized: %d", scores.count);
}
```

Sorry for all the code but pretty much all this code comes from this library's file: https://github.com/csddavies/DDGameKitHelper/blob/master/DDGameKitHelper.m

Anyway how would I fix this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: And whence comes the scores array?

Comment: I have added that info! :) Whoops sorry, you said score array, I thought you said category. I'll add that in a minute.

Comment: Ok I added that info now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GameKit reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

> To report a score to Game Center, your game allocates and initializes a new object, sets the [`value`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKScore/value) property to the score the player earned, and then calls the `reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:` method.

Most likely it's complaining because you haven't set the `value` property, but it's also possible that you're missing the first step too -- i.e. it doesn't like you submitting `GKScore` objects that came from a leaderboard instead of ones you create yourself.

Comment: That's what I was figuring, I fixed it!